# Android canvas drawing semi transparent figures, so they overlay each other

Tags: android, canvas

On a canvas I draw figures covering each-other to get the result I want. Their transparent is 128 and on cover areas color multiple. I need whole figure in one color. How to fix it?

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        Path path =  new Path();
        path.moveTo(margin,0);
        path.lineTo(middleWidth+pieceWidth,0);
        path.lineTo(middleWidth-pieceWidth,height);
        path.lineTo(margin, height);
        path.lineTo(margin, 0);

        Path path1 = new Path();
        path1.moveTo(middleWidth+pieceWidth+interval,0);
        path1.lineTo(middleWidth-pieceWidth+interval,height);
        path1.lineTo(width-margin,height);
        path1.lineTo(width-margin,0);
        path1.lineTo(middleWidth+pieceWidth+interval,0);


        RectF rect = new RectF();
        rect.set(0,0,middleWidth-pieceWidth,height);

        RectF rect1 = new RectF();
        rect1.set(middleWidth+pieceWidth,0,width,height);


        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        paint.setColor(leftColor);
        paint.setAlpha(128);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        paint.setColor(rightColor);
        paint.setAlpha(128);
        canvas.drawPath(path1, paint);
        paint.setAlpha(128);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corners, corners, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect1, corners, corners, paint);
    }
```

The result is:

[Result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrf8.jpg)

Comment: try reading about porter duff xfer modes